# Nvidia GPU temperature shown twice in conky

Tags: nvidia, 14.10, temperature, conky

My problem is, that in Ubuntu 14.10 the old ${nvidia temp} code is not working, I use this code instead: `${execi 60 nvidia-settings -query GPUCoreTemp | perl -ne 'print $1 if /GPUCoreTemp.*?: (\d+)./;'} °C`
But this code shows the temperature twice, why could that be?

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9xKa.png)

The output of `nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp`:

```
slaci@slaci-comp:~$ nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp

  Attribute 'GPUCoreTemp' (slaci-comp:0.0): 63.
    'GPUCoreTemp' is an integer attribute.
    'GPUCoreTemp' is a read-only attribute.
    'GPUCoreTemp' can use the following target types: X Screen, GPU.
  Attribute 'GPUCoreTemp' (slaci-comp:0[gpu:0]): 63.
    'GPUCoreTemp' is an integer attribute.
    'GPUCoreTemp' is a read-only attribute.
    'GPUCoreTemp' can use the following target types: X Screen, GPU.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try your code/shell script in a terminal to see exactly what it will output. It's probably supplying the double results, then you can troubleshoot it in a terminal.

```
nvidia-settings -query GPUCoreTemp | perl -ne 'print $1 if /GPUCoreTemp.*?: (\d+)./;'
```

Just saw your updated Q, with the output from nvidia-settings it's printing the temperature twice for some reason. One of them contains "gpu" which is easy to grab with a `grep` to then pipe only one temp into your `perl` script, so this should work

```
nvidia-settings -query GPUCoreTemp| grep gpu | perl -ne 'print $1 if /GPUCoreTemp.*?: (\d+)./;'
```

And if it all gets put together into the conkyrc it should look like this:

```
${execi 60 nvidia-settings -query GPUCoreTemp| grep gpu | perl -ne 'print $1 if /GPUCoreTemp.*?: (\d+)./;'} °C
```

Conky should only print what the shell returns to it, and testing `exec` codes in a terminal is more enlightening than running through Conky, can see error messages that Conky ignores (I think it only uses stdout).

I don't have `nvidia-settings` so I can't test it, but here are some alternative scripts / commands that should return the GPU's temp; you'll have to look at the output of `nvidia-settings` to determine what to search for & cut, if it's changed & these don't work anymore.

From  [1st forum find](http://www.phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?68383-nVidia-GPU-temperature-monitor)

- `nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp -t`
- `nvidia-smi -a | grep Gpu`
- `nvclock -T`

From [2nd forum find](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/take-nvidia-gpu-temp-on-conky.13919/)

- `nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp |grep '):' | cut -d ' ' -f 6,6 | sed -e 's/.\{1\}$//'`
- `nvidia-settings -t -q localhost:0/gpucoretemp`

Comment: None of these worked for me, except the 1st one from the 2nd forum that gives me the temperature twice again. My Ubuntu is also freshly installed, so there shouldn't be any junk that causes such an error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SomogyiLászló try and run `nvidia-settings -q gpucoretemp` alone in a terminal, and paste that into your question (edit). Then you can see what's going on & customize the rest to work

Comment: @SomogyiLászló  Also I think there was a formatting mixup in the 2nd forum (1st line) code that you tried, might be working better now. Or if not you can try deleting everything after & including the last `|` ("pipe" character) to see what `cut` returns, and try deleting after the next last `|` to see what `grep` returns, back to just the `nvidia`... part, to split it up & see what's going on

Comment: The 1st code from the 2nd forum now gives me the temerature once, but everything after that code disappeared from the running conky, including the "°C".

Comment: @Slaci Just saw your output from nvidia-settings too, it outputs the temperature twice for some reason. The second time it contains "gpu" which is easy to grab with a`grep` and then pipe just the one temp into your perl code, so adding that should make your original code work. I'll update my answer with it, hopefully it will work & you can mark it the correct / check-marked answer :)

Comment: Thanks, it works now properly. Happy holidays to you! :)